# R session terminated data lost

Tags: r, memory, data-storage

I collected a 2.5GB matrix with R, and upon its completion, I accidentally passed a view command to the RStudio

```
 View(Matrix)
```

So the RStudio stuck and force quit. I lost all the data. Is there any possibility that R could have stored some of the data somewhere? If yes, where could I find them? I am using a Mac.

Comment: There might be an `*.Rdata` file in your standard working directory, should be the newest. Have you tried just to restart RStudio?